# How does consumption of vinegar affect food chemistry?

Tags: food, nutrition, digestive-system, digestion, carbohydrates

For example: does consumption of vinegar somehow change digestion of flour (bread, cakes, pasta, puffs) ? May be there are some benefits to eat flour meal with vinegar ?

Comment: How much vinegar are you talking about? 50ml? 500? 2L? What sort of "benefits" are you expecting? And could you define "dough" - do you mean uncooked bread dough, or something else?

Comment: @MattDMo I mean bread, cakes, pasta... quantity to taste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case you're talking about (just using vinegar to taste), there should be no effect whatsoever on a healthy stomach. The stomach already contains a significant amount of [acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gastric_acid), and a little bit more from the [acetic acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acetic_acid) in vinegar won't change much, just like eating some citrus fruit with a meal (oranges, lemons, and whatnot) won't change much. Acid-mediated hydrolysis of chewed food is only the first of many steps in digestion - a significant portion is performed by enzymes and commensal microorganisms in the gut. Changing the type or amount of acid by a small amount won't affect anything significantly in the long run.

The only exception I can think of is for people suffering from [peptic ulcers](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/pepticulcer.html), whether from over-use of [NSAIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonsteroidal_anti-inflammatory_drug) (Non-Steroidal Anti-Inflammatory Drugs such as aspirin, ibuprofen, naproxen, etc.), infection with [*H. pylori*](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/helicobacterpyloriinfections.html), or possible genetic/developmental issues (most often seen in young children). In these cases, consuming an overly-acidic meal may aggravate the symptoms of peptic ulceration.